# Running Protractor on a browser without a dedicated WebDriver implementation?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webkit, webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to set up end-to-end tests for an AngularJS web app. I want to run the tests on a device with a quite rare WebKit based browser, which has no WebDriver implementation. Currently we're using *angular-scenario* which works just fine, but since that's [deprecated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/guide/e2e-testing), using Protractor would be more future-proof.

Is there a WebDriver implementation, implementing a sub-set of the WebDriver interface, for browsers currently missing a dedicated WebDriver implementation?

Comment: What rare WebKit based browser are you using?

Comment: In this case it's a browser designed for running on set-top boxes.

Comment: Are you able to launch the browser via an external script and run your unit tests via karma on it.  You may need to create a driver for your WebKit based browser that exposes control to launch pages, click on elements or coordinates and inspect the dom.

Comment: Yes, we're currently using Karma to run our angular-scenario tests on the device.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no WebDriver for the WebKit based browser you're using, there is no easy way about it.

Using protractor is ideal as it controls the browser at a higher level than `angular-scenario`. `angular-scenario` in theory is a WebSocket connection controlling and asserting on a iFrame, this starts to break down when the guest source doesn't want to be in a iFrame and other abnormalities that generally are not experienced that present false positives.

As the particulars to the WebKit version are not released, I can only offer a few suggestions what I would attempt next.

You have only a couple choices:

1. Ask the browser developers to point you to a Selenium WebDriver implementation.
2. Build your own WebDriver as an extension that communicates over WebSocket's, using [SafariDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/safari-driver) for reference.
3. Stick with `angular-scenario`, or somewhat a version there of.

Good luck with your project.